# Toolbar in android

Tags: android, layout, toolbar

Is there any tutorial easy to understand to create a toolbar with the home button aligned to the left and the log out button aligned to the right?

I am using menu type .xml files to do it, but I am not able to align the buttons as I want.

My .xml is:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/etxera"
        android:icon="@drawable/etxera_fondo"
        android:title="Hasierara"

        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item android:id="@+id/saioa_itxi"
        android:icon="@drawable/saioaitxi"
        android:title="saioa itxi"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />
</menu>
```

Thanks for support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a custom toolbar

1. Create a xml file

**toolbar.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:titleTextColor="#FFFFFF">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/left_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/right_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right" />
        </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

1. Include the toolbar into your main_activity.xml

   ```
    <RelativeLayout 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <include
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       layout="@layout/toolbar" />

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

Don't forget to set the NoActionBar theme